# Gazebo stuck waiting for Master in Groovy

Tags: gazebo, master, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to run the latest public Groovy gazebo build under Ubuntu 12.04, but the process hangs waiting for the master:

```
    tor1pal@thror:groovy$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch 
... logging to /home/tor1pal/.ros/log/a3bb5152-81fb-11e2-b3dc-78acc0be2023/roslaunch-thror-4864.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://thror:52847/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4878]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to a3bb5152-81fb-11e2-b3dc-78acc0be2023
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [4891]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [4905]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [4916]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
Set SDF value
  Version[1.2] to Version[1.3]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Msg Waiting for master.[ INFO] [1362092857.805255296]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56660/gazebo-stuck-waiting-for-master-in-groovy/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-02-28**:
can you post the results of these commands: 'ifconfig' and 'env | grep ROS'
There seems to be a mismatch between the roslaunch server and your master uri. IIRC this will be a problem

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-03-02**:
Did you find out what caused this yet? I am having the same problems at the moment.

**Comment by [Robotnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1119/robotnik/) on 2013-03-17**:
Hi, I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen a similar problem if your network connection is unplugged.

Apparently ROS requires a live network port even if you're running everything on one machine (at least if you have an IP assigned to your hostname).

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) with karma: 476 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2013-02-28**:
I do have a valid network connection (using the same machine to make this post :) ).